# Talend tDRow component gives error ORA-00933

Tags: sql, talend, ora-00933

I'm using the component tDBRow in Talend where I execute a simple query, that is the following:

```
" 
insert into test.wk_sf_l_srv_cshistory_to_load select
ID, 
CREATEDDATE
from test.CASE_HISTORY_FULL
where createddate >=  " +context.builtIn_lastRunDate +  " "
```

but when I launch my job the error `ora-00933 sql command not properly ended` pops out. Is this a context variable use problem? I've searched and seen I could write like this but it doesn't work.

EDIT I've tried the same query in SQL Developer, using a random date, and no error is given.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not correctly constructing your query. I'm guessing `context.builtIn_lastRunDate` is a string, so you should enclose it in quotes like so:

```
"insert into test.wk_sf_l_srv_cshistory_to_load select
ID, 
CREATEDDATE
from test.CASE_HISTORY_FULL
where createddate >=  '" + context.builtIn_lastRunDate +  "'"
```

If `context.builtIn_lastRunDate` is of date type, you need to format it to a string like so:

```
".. where createddate >= '" + TalendDate.formatDate("<date format here>", context.builtIn_lastRunDate) + "'"
```

Comment: lastRunDate is a date, and if I use that method it tells me there are problem with the parenthesis, even if they are ok...